# How to get tomcat log from docker container running in atomic host

Tags: docker, logstash, tomcat8, rsyslog

I am working on Log monitoring, I have requirement of getting tomcat application server logs(example: catalina.log) running in the docker container(container is running in atomic host) and passing it to Logstash server using rsyslog.
I am able to get the docker container related logs, but not able to get the tomcat server and application logs from the docker container where tomcat is running.
Any suggestion on this is appreciated.

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: How do you start the container? Do you share a volume?

Comment: I am not using mount volume, I am running docker container in the Kubernetes pod.

Answer (score 1):

You could mount the local host when initializing the container.  You just pass `-v` flag for mounting to the local host.

`docker run -v /tmp may/hello-world.py`

This will allow you to mount the directory of the tomcat logs to the local host.

Here is the Docker Docs that talks about it.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

-Bruce

Comment: Thank you Bruce, I will try this way